# Error using capybara-webkit for scraping in ubuntu server amazon Capybara::Webkit::ConnectionError (/path/webkit_server failed to start.):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-server, capybara-webkit

I have this code in my controller:

```
browser = Capybara.current_session
browser.visit url[0]
```

And it gets error in visit method.

I've installed lib qt5 in my server, i know that i need to use an xserver, but i've installed without changes in the log.

Any suggestions? I think is a server configuration or lib.
PD: in development mode, in my laptop, everything works perfectly, it brokes in production mode.

Comment: What's the value of `url[0]`?, try `browser.save_and_open_screenshot` after the `visit` command.

Comment: url[0] is a route, the scraping works fine in development mode, but in production i'm getting this error:
Capybara::Webkit::ConnectionError (/home/ubuntu/apps/bescrapper/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0/bin/webkit_server failed to start.):

Comment: Did you installed an tested phantomjs, what about qt?

Comment: Qt5 is installed by qt5-default, mmm but phantomjs is not, it's a dependency for capybara-webkit?

Comment: PhantomJS is not required for capybara-webkit, but you do need Qt 5.5.x (or possibly a newer Qt with a manually installed QtWebKit)

Comment: Maybe as I haven't seen your code, I thought mistakenly, I could recommend you to use capybara/poltergeist which depends on Phantomjs to scrape data.

Comment: i've installed phantomjs, and changed capybara webkit for poltergeist, and it works perfectly in development, i deployed it in my server(after install phantomjs), and i get this error:

ArgumentError (The detector #<struct Cliver::Detector command_arg=nil, version_pattern=nil> failed to detect theversion of the executable at '/usr/bin/phantomjs')

And executing: 
phantomjs -v

outputs:

QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the bug reporting guide at
<http://phantomjs.org/bug-reporting.html> and file a bug report.
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: btw: QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.5.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

Comment: @fabian818 To use Poltergeist download and use the phantomjs binary from the PhantomJS project https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/releases -  The one provided by Ubuntu is broken in a number of ways (requires X for a headless driver, file upload requires an extra click, etc)

Comment: Yep, that's right, that was the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank's guys for giving me clues.
1. Change webkit to poltergeist gem. It have the same result, but better functionality in servers. https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist
2. Install phantomjs (dependency for poltergeist) by binaries. https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#installing-phantomjs

And that's all.